# why does nslogging stop when i come back from background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

I have an app that i want it to start from the beginning whenever the home button is pressed and the app is then relaunched. So I have the plist bool set to yes so app does not run in background.
All of this works fine and the app appears to work except that once the app goes into the background because the home button was pressed and then started again I lose all of the nslogging to the console, but the app appears to run fine.
When I start the app again from Xcode everything looks fine.
Any suggestions as to why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read output from NSLog in the Xcode debugger or in the Organizer for an attached device?

If your application does in fact stop running when the home button is pressed and restarts with a new process, the debugger won't be attached anymore (it was attached to the previous process ID) and you won't see any log messages there.

Comment: Aha! Very interesting.  Is there a way to force it to restart?  I am reading it in the debugger window of Xcode

Comment: You can attach the debugger to a process using `Product > Attach to Process`. Your app should be listed under "Likely targets"

Comment: I tried to do this but when I select the process listed I get this message. Xcode couldn't attach to “theApp”. “theApp” does not support a debuggable architecture.